# Git Alias для открытия страницы создания Pull Request

Tags: git

Как можно открыть страницу из git, чтобы создать ПР, удается распознавать исходную ветку а так же открывать нужный URL, но под подставить branch в URL не удается, открывает страницу без переменной `BRANCH`

```
pullrq="!f() { \
    BRANCH=$(git rev-parse --abbrev-ref HEAD); \
    git push -u origin "${BRANCH}"; \
    start "https://bitbucket/...\"${BRANCH}\""; \
    };f"
```

Comment: Во первых у вас какая-то беда с кавычками, а во вторых какая у вас операционная система?

Comment: Я игрался по разному с кавычками, пытался и через экранирование, не помогает, просто скопировал последную верси. А ОС у меня Windows 10 но пользуюсь gitbash. @AlexeyTen

Comment: start это не отдельная программа, а команда оболочки cmd

Comment: Да так и есть, это команда cmd, но что делать то чтобы подставить переменную?